# Cannot import react custom components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, export, react-component

I am learning react and currently using CDNs. I have been trying to import a header component but am unable to do so. I have been trying to see what is wrong in the code but can't find any. I am getting a blank page if I try to import.

react1.js

```
import Header from "./Header";

function MainContent(){
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Reasons why I'm excited to learn React</h1>
            <ol>
                <li>By knowing React, my chances of getting hired increases</li>
                <li>It is easy to write and understand</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    );
}

function Footer(){
    return (
        <footer className="Footer">
            <small>2022 Naik development. All Rights Reserved.</small>
        </footer>
    );
}

function Page(){
    return (
        <div>
            <Header/>
            <MainContent/>
            <Footer/>
        </div>
    );
}
ReactDOM.render(<Page/>,document.getElementById("root"))
```

Header.js

```
export default function Header(){
    return(
        <header>
            <nav className="Navbar">
                <img src="./react1-logo.png" className="nav-logo"></img>
                <ul className="NavMenu">
                    <li>Pricing</li>
                    <li>About</li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you show your files structure?

Answer (score 0):

- rename your file to .jsx instead of js
- check if folder structure is correct or not!

Comment: to add more, jsx files is javascript xml which you can use html like syntax, it is an extension of js. read more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using functional component,Try to import react on top of the header.js file to make it work . new code looks like below.

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Header() {
  return (
    <header>
      <nav className="Navbar">
        <img src="./react1-logo.png" className="nav-logo"></img>
        <ul className="NavMenu">
          <li>Pricing</li>
          <li>About</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working, Please check this codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-gianmarco-uj70po)!